# Remove first and last backslash?

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I have created a sample data generator in javascript and the output is a json object that is stringified. Now I need to remove the first/last backslash from each element in the output.

Current output is:

```
array(\"'This is' a test\",\"Testie Test\",\"Bob the tester\",\"Wanna test "some" more\")
```

Output needed:

```
array("'This is' a test","Testie Test","Bob the tester","Wanna test \"some\" more")
```

I need the text that is double quoted to be escaped but I need to remove the first and last backslash as the data is then copied and uploaded to another tool and breaks with these backslashes.

I can easily remove all backslashes with a simple regex:

```
var = var.replace(/\\\\/g,"")
```

however then the inside text no longer is escaped. I have tried variations of more complex regexes to accomplish this with no success. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you removing all the backslashes? JSON encodes the text with backslashes to escape quotes.

Comment: What is the original JSON? In the format of `{"name": value, ...}`

Comment: @BitByte because the first/last backslash breaks the 2nd tool that is using this sample data. Until I can create a web service to the 2nd tool this is a necessary step.

Comment: Yes it is {"city_name": "vancouver", "prov": "bc", ...}

Comment: Disregard above ...  Original is:    {"id":"xxxx", "data":["text","text","text",...]},{"id":"xxx", "data":[ ..... ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `JSON.parse(object)`. It should return the entire object, parsed.

Furthermore, `console.log(JSON.parse(object)["data"])` should print the entire value as a array.

According to your comment, considering the json is formatted as so: `{"records": [{"id":"xxxx", "data":["text","text","text",...]},{"id":"xxx", "data":[ ..... ]},...]}`

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(object);
var output = []
for (var i = 0; parsed["records"].length < i; i++) {
  output.push(parsed["records"][i]["data"]);
}
document.getElementById("textareafieldid").value = output;
```

Do make sure to set the id of the textfield in the script the same as defined in the HTML.

```
<textarea id='textareafieldid'></textarea>
```

Comment: The output goes to a textarea field in a web app not console. Apologize I am new to javascript and I am getting no output when trying this

Comment: This is browser javascript? Not running node or anything?

Comment: Yes correct... I took the project over and in the process of rewriting in php and creating a web service but need to fix this as it is used frequently

Comment: Thanks that did the trick! Appreciate everyone's responses and help.

Answer (score 1):

`^(\\.)*(\\).$` would match the first backslash and the backslash right before the last character.

Instead of regexps, you can directly test if your string begins with a `\"` and ends with a `\"`:

```
if (s.startsWith('\\"') && s.endsWith('\\"')) {
  clean_s = '"' + s.substr(2, s.length-4) + '"';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to match your strings :

```
^\\(.*)\\(")$
```

The first capture group will capture the entire string excluding the starting backslash but it won't capture the last qoutes. The last qoutes will be captured in group 2. You can concatenate these two groups to get your desired output!

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TwH589/1)